# name as email link if email !empty else name

Tags: php, mysql

A form sends name, topic, email, and blurb to MySQL db. Email is not a required field, but if it is !empty I want to include it as the name and echo the row data.

This is my idea so far:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $row['name'] = "<A href='mailto:' . $_POST['email'] . '>' . $_POST['name'] . '</A>";
}
else
    {
        $row['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    }
```

I am having trouble sorting out the coding for the email/name any help please. And the rows will be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><Posted by : ' . $row['name'] . ' on ' . $row['date'] . '<br />
        Topic : ' . $row['topic'] . '<br />Thoughts : ' . $row['thoughts'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
```

Not very well sorted yet, help please :-) thanks.

Comment: How does the top snippet relate to the bottom snippet?

Comment: What kind of trouble? What is happening? We need more details!

Comment: What is your $result looks like? Does it have any `ORDER BY` clause or not. Please give us a detailed code.

Comment: What's wrong with the top snippet? It seems to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. The data is displayed by date descending. The problem is I don't know enough, I think to assimilate the bits of code. I just get the name, but it is not email also.

Answer (score 0):

are you want that if the email is not empty then you want to replace it with name and echo it? if yes then try the below code..

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $row['name'] =$_POST['email'];

 $row['name']="<A href='mailto:' . $_POST['email'] . '>' . $_POST['name'] . '</A>";
}
else
    {
        $row['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. We are in different time zones, hence delay in reply :-).  The data is displayed by date descending. The problem is I don't know enough, I think to assimilate the bits of code. Can't put code in as over the word limit, so please go here http://www.albob.org.nz/example.html for the code and info. Thanks.